# I want to use one core library with different versions of JUMIO SDK for different purposes but I'm getting following error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-resources, aapt

Below are the dependencies that I'm using

```
implementation "com.jumio.android:core:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:core:3.9.2"
implementation "com.jumio.android:linefinder:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:mrz:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:nfc:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:barcode:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:barcode-mlkit:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:iproov:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:defaultui:4.0.0"
implementation "com.jumio.android:dv:3.9.2"
```

Error Image is attached,Below is the link of that image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeHoI.png

If i include,implementation "com.jumio.android:dv:3.9.2" dependency error occurs.This dependency needs implementation "com.jumio.android:core:3.9.2" Core dependency.

Comment: Maybe you should use the same version for all libraries

Comment: Yes,But for documentation SDK Core library version 4.0.0 is not available